# Mongoose Remove Error Object has no method remove

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I try to find and remove an item.

Here is my code , its simple:

```
playlistItem.find( { $and: [ { songId : data.songId }, { userAdded : data.userAdded } , { playlistId : data.playlistId } ] } ).limit(1).lean().exec(function(err, item){
                            if (!item) {
                                    callback(null,{message:"playlist item not found"})
                            }else{
                                // delete playlist item
                                  item.remove(function(err) {
                                    if (err){
                                        callback( new Error('new error') );
                                    }else{
                                        callback(null,{message:"playlist successfully removed"})
                                    } 


                                  });   
                            }
                        })
```

i want first find my item and then remove it

when i run this code i get this  error:

```
item.remove(function(err) {
                                                                       ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'remove'
```

I want know where i am wrong.

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to delete the object. Obviously, the model does not have such a method to delete it directly.

Since you are using Mongoose, this is the query that deletes an object from the database:

```
Model.remove({ id: X }, function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // removed!
});
```

So, in your case, I would assume that something like this should work:

```
PlayListItems.remove({ id: item.id }, function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // removed!
});
```

Comment: one question , in this way how we can check an item already removed ?

Comment: Well, you can call the find method to see if the record with that id exists?